# Checking multiple values in a column for a condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
person    product
P1        A
P1        B
P1        C
P2        A
P2        B
P2        D
P3        A
```

I need to write a SQL query to select person who uses product A and B, but not the product C.

I tried using AND and IN operator, but it obviously shouldnt work as the result is expecting it to be.

Here the expected result is:

```
P2
```

Comment: Go on . Try something.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT person
FROM source_table
GROUP BY person
HAVING SUM(product = 'A')      -- at least one
   AND SUM(product = 'B')      -- at least one
   AND NOT SUM(product = 'C')  -- strictly none
```

---

Comparing result is treated as 1 when matched (is TRUE) and as 0 when not matched (is FALSE). So SUMs in HAVING simply counted rows in a group which matches the condition.

Of course full condition form needs `SUM(product = 'A') > 0` and `SUM(product = 'C') = 0`. But MySQL treates zero as FALSe and any non-zero as TRUE, so additional compare is excess.

---

This technique allows you to create more complex conditions. For example:

- at least one A or B: `SUM(product IN ('A', 'B'))`
- at least two from the list A,B,C: `SUM(product IN ('A', 'B', 'C')) >= 2`
- 2 or 3 from the list A,B,C,D: `SUM(product IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')) BETWEEN 2 AND 3`

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

```
SELECT person, GROUP_CONCAT(product) AS all_products
FROM mytable
GROUP BY person
HAVING all_products REGEXP ('A') 
AND all_products REGEXP ('B')
AND all_products NOT REGEXP ('C');
```

Comment: If a person has product `'AB'` then excess output rows will be selected.

Comment: True, but that was not in the scope of the question. And it seems unlikely to me that a product has a name that is the concatenation of two other product names. But nevertheless, your answer is the more elegant and foolproof way.

Comment: It is more safe to use `HAVING FIND_IN_SET('A', GROUP_CONCAT(product))` - this will fix described issue (but will fail if `product` value may contain commas).

Comment: I didn't know about FIND_IN_SET. Thanks for pointing that out.